Using zip to create a dictionary doesn't result in a dictionary of the same length when list items repeat
Zipping does not do what I thought, it seems to drop items.
names = ['nik', 'katie', 'james', "katie"]
ages = [32, 31, 34, 106]
my_dict = dict(zip(names, ages))
print(my_dict)

This gives:
{'nik': 32, 'katie': 106, 'james': 34}

Where did my younger Katie go? And how do I use zip to create a dictionary that keeps my original list length and doesn't drop any items?

It is not zip causing the issue. Dictionaries cannot have duplicated keys.

thankyou, that makes sense. Very happy with that.

What did you expect to see as output? If you weren't using zip and wrote {'nik': 32, 'katie': 31, 'james': 34, 'katie': 106} you'd see the same result.

I didn't realize that about dictionaries, that really helps thanks. Kind of new to python

python::datastructure::dict::with the requirement that the keys are unique

i realize then that the problem i am solving will be solved by placing my key values around the other way, that way my keys will be unique. Thanks all, just had my big reveal on dictionaries and I'm good now

Python dictionary cannot have two same keys
